# Sitecore Lucene.net search with " Item name" only and sort it by hits

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

Hi how can we search an items name (http://screencast.com/t/vRAUNgQN)  using Lucene.net in Sitecore and sort the search by the hits.

Comment: What have you tried already and what resources have you already looked at? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't really be a question as there are lots of resources out there for this. This is my goto place for search:

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team.aspx

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt though and get you started.

If you are using Sitecore 7 and above you can use the Linq style search.

```
using (var context = new ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("indexname").CreateSearchContext())
{
   IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query =context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>   ().Where(p=> p["name"].Equals("John"));
}
```

You can then call

```
  SearchResults<SearchResultItem> results = query.GetResults();
```

This will have a hits collection

```
 foreach (var hit in results.Hits)
 {
         hit.Document.Id;

         var relevance = hit.Score;
 ........
```

Each hit will have a Score property which determines relevance (see above) - you should be able to sort by this. By default I think it sorts by relvance anyway. You can change the relvency by using the Boost function in the query.

For Sitecore 6.6

I'm a big fan of advanced database crawler module - it provides a nice wrapper for the search logic that sits on top of the standard search api.

http://sitecoresupport.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/advanced-database-crawler-sitecore.html

Bear in mind though if you upgrade to 7 there are compatibility issues with this module.

Or you can use the standard Sitecore search api

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/articles%202/administration/lucene%20search/lcd/lucene_search_engine-a4.pdf

I'm sure you'll figure the rest out

Comment: Thanks for the input .How can i sort based on the highest rank first ?

Comment: See amends above relating to the score property - hope this helps.

Comment: i am still on sitecore 6.6 just to let you know.

Comment: No problem, don't  forget to mark as answer if your question was answered. Thanks